# Не работает require_once __DIR__

Tags: php

Ситуация. php7, OpenServer. Включен error_reporting(E_ALL);

При подключении скрипта `require_once __DIR__ . "/url/script.php";` выполнение скрипта прекращается

Вывод `__DIR__` показывает D:\OSPanel\domains\testdomain

При подключении скрипта через include без `__DIR__` скрипт продолжает выполняться,  но при этом без `__DIR__` все подключения скрипта ломаются

При включении ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); стало показывать ошибку

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory i.
```

Но при этом сам скрипт и путь к нему существуют. Однако корень сайта обычно получают для прописывания путей через $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Но print $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; в данном случае выдает ответ папку домена - testdomain

известно, что у человека, писавшего скрипт, все работало через `__DIR__`. Почему же в данном случае не завелось? И что же делать?

Таким образом вся соль в неверном

Comment: Текст ошибки __полностью__

Comment: что такое "все подключения скрипта"?

Comment: возможно у пользователя, от которого выполняется скрипт нет прав на чтение на файл `/url/script.php`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а это ничего что при отсутствии прав выводится совсем другая ошибка?

Comment: @Ипатьев да, погорячился

Comment: @katyka а что выдает `__DIR__ . "/url/script.php"` и совпадает ли это с вашим файлом?